# PubCenter ads are not displaying with adrotator

Tags: windows-phone-8, ads, adrotator

I'm using AdRotator in my WP8 app, and while AdDuplex ads display just fine, PubCenter ads are not displaying.
I saw that it was normal it does not appear in emulator.
But I tested "device" mode and it does not appear either. 
I also tried to publish my app with 50/50 parameter for AdDuplex and PubCenter, and the only advertisements we see are those of AdDuplex.

Note that I use AdDuplex version 2.1.0-Beta1.

Here's my xaml:

```
<adRotator:AdRotatorControl 
                    x:Name="AdRotatorControl"
                    Grid.Row="3"
                    AdHeight="80" AdWidth="480"
                    Margin="-12,253,0,-243"
                    LocalSettingsLocation="defaultAdSettings.xml"
                    AutoStartAds="True" />
```

And the 'defaultAdSettings.xml' file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AdSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CultureDescriptors CultureName="">
    <AdDuplex AppId="950XX" Probability="50"/>
    <PubCenter AppId="767b12XX-bcXX-41XX-a5XX-333ba4afb0XX" SecondaryId="107299XX" Probability="50"/>
    </CultureDescriptors>
</AdSettings>
```

Even if I specify the parameters 100 (pubCenter) / 0 (AdDuplex) nothing appears.
And i have checked  thoses capabilities :

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER"/>
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO"/>
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER" />
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
```

Someone would have an idea why my PubCenter ads do not appear?

Comment: @Goeffrey how did you add the rference to the Microsoft Advertising SDK? I'm having the same trouble

Comment: @TripVoltage : Install Microsoft Advertising SDK, if not already, and add reference. In the Solution Explorer, right-click on References and select “Add Reference”.  Then go on Windows phone tab, extensions and select the Microsoft Advertising SDK and click OK (I think it can change slightly depending on the version of visual studio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself after long searches. 
To use "pubCenter" with "AdRotator", the following points should be well done:

1) Having checked the Capacities

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER"/> 
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO"/> 
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" /> 
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER" /> 
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
```

2) Add reference to the Microsoft Advertising SDK

My mistake here was to have forgotten the reference to the SDK. But now everything works fine :)